# Reload/History behaviour in Get and Post request?

Tags: java, web-applications, post, get, httprequest

I went thru http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp to read
about read vs post.Here is the description

[image]

To clear confusion, I am just taking scenario where user  creates the customer on page 1(with the submit button) and 
navigates to success page(page 2).

For reload (say user press F5 on success page) point, Get request is said to be harmless where in post request
 "Data will be re-submitted".

> My understanding in both request (GET/POST), data will be resubmitted
>   . so in customer  scenario, two customer will be created when user
>   press F5 on page whether its post or get. So  as per my 
>   understanding, Data will be re-submitted in both GET/POST request and
>   none is harmless.Please correct my  understanding if it is wrong?

For History point. It is said in GET request ,"Parameters remain in browser history" and for POST request
 "Parameters are not saved in browser history". My question is if request parameters are not saved in 
 browser history in post request, how on click of F5  on success page duplicate customer is created. Are they stored
 at some other location instead of browser history in post request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to explain point by point:

**About GET being harmless**: Method GET is supossed to de idempotent, that means: given the same url and the same parameters it always should return the same result (user=34,date=01-07-2013 should return the same page) and SHOULDN'T change anything (do nothing more than a sort of query with "user" and "date"). Of course is quite common to break this rule and actually change the internal state (do an update or the like) that is the case that you're mentioning (page1 --> page2 creating something). POST requests don't have that requirement and are meant to change the internal state.

**About parameters remaining in browser history**: What they really mean is that in the GET request parameters are contained in the URL itself ( *mysite.com?user=34,date=01-07-2013* ) so if you save the URL you also saving the parameters. In a POST request parameters go in the body of the request rather than as part of the URL; so you're right, old browsers used to only store the URL, nowadays browsers are optimized to store those POST parameters in an internal cache.

Comment: i think you meant "GET requests don't have that requirement and are meant to change the internal state." instead of POST requests don't have that requirement and are meant to change the internal state.

Comment: English is not my first language, so I'll try to rephrase: GETs shouldn't change/create/delete anything. POSTs are ok to change anything